# Why do I get this error when I deploy a Django App in Railway?

Tags: python, django, psycopg2, deploying

There is a problem when I deploy a Django app in Railway, Railway is an infrastructure platform that is very similar to Heroku and it uses debian, this is the error that is in the logs.

```
#10 16.69   Using cached selenium-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (958 kB)
#10 16.75 Collecting six==1.16.0
 
#10 16.75   Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
#10 16.78 Collecting sniffio==1.2.0
#10 16.78   Using cached sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
#10 16.83 Collecting sortedcontainers==2.4.0
#10 16.83   Using cached sortedcontainers-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
#10 16.89 Collecting soupsieve==2.2.1
 
#10 16.89   Using cached soupsieve-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
#10 16.93 Collecting sqlparse==0.4.2
#10 16.93   Using cached sqlparse-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
 
#10 17.07 Collecting tqdm==4.62.3
#10 17.08   Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
#10 17.12 Collecting trio==0.19.0
#10 17.12   Using cached trio-0.19.0-py3-none-any.whl (356 kB)
#10 17.16 Collecting trio-websocket==0.9.2
 
#10 17.16   Using cached trio_websocket-0.9.2-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
#10 17.23 Collecting twine==3.4.2
#10 17.24   Using cached twine-3.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
#10 17.28 Collecting tzdata==2022.1
 
#10 17.29   Using cached tzdata-2022.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (339 kB)
#10 17.38 Collecting urllib3==1.26.6
#10 17.38   Using cached urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
#10 17.41 Collecting webencodings==0.5.1
 
#10 17.42   Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
#10 17.47 Collecting whitenoise==6.2.0
#10 17.47   Using cached whitenoise-6.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
#10 17.51 Collecting wsproto==1.0.0
#10 17.51   Using cached wsproto-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
 
#10 17.57 Collecting zipp==3.6.0
#10 17.57   Using cached zipp-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
 
#10 18.00 Collecting psycopg2
 
#10 18.00   Using cached psycopg2-2.9.3.tar.gz (380 kB)
#10 18.09   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
 
#10 18.38   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#10 18.39   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 18.39
#10 18.39   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#10 18.39   │ exit code: 1
#10 18.39   ╰─> [23 lines of output]
#10 18.39       running egg_info
#10 18.39       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bw0tcpyi/psycopg2.egg-info
#10 18.39       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bw0tcpyi/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
#10 18.39       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bw0tcpyi/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
#10 18.39       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bw0tcpyi/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
#10 18.39       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-bw0tcpyi/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
#10 18.39
#10 18.39       Error: pg_config executable not found.
#10 18.39
#10 18.39       pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
#10 18.39       containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
#10 18.39       option:
#10 18.39
#10 18.39           python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
#10 18.39
#10 18.39       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
#10 18.39
#10 18.39       If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
#10 18.39       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
#10 18.39
#10 18.39       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
#10 18.39       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>;).
#10 18.39
#10 18.39       [end of output]
#10 18.39
#10 18.39   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#10 18.39 error: metadata-generation-failed
#10 18.39
#10 18.39 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
 
#10 18.39 ╰─> See above for output.
#10 18.39
#10 18.39 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#10 18.39 hint: See above for details.
#10 18.40 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
#10 18.40 You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
 
#10 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c python -m venv /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
-----
> [stage-0 6/9] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/d3b41cd2-3817-4a81-ba7d-ff021a7d5a6f-/root/.cache/pip,target=/root/.cache/pip python -m venv /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt:
-----
executor failed running [/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c python -m venv /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt]: exit code: 1
 
Error: Docker build failed
```

The error could be "Error: pg_config executable not found.", so I have looked up the error in Google, and I got that I have to change the library "psycopg2" to "psycopg2-binary", but I still get the same error.

After I tried a "template" in railway, which is like configurations for each framework, and it brings a sample app to test with, in this case, it was a Django app, in that app I saw that the dependency "psycopg2" was the version "2.8.6", and it was working, so I also replaced the version "2.9.3" to "2.8.6", but with the same result, even with replacing it with the dependency "psycopg2-binary".

This is the requirement.txt file:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
async-generator==1.10
attrs==21.4.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
bleach==4.1.0
cached-property==1.5.2
certifi==2021.5.30
cffi==1.15.0
charset-normalizer==2.0.6
cloudinary==1.29.0
colorama==0.4.4
coverage==6.4.1
cryptography==36.0.1
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.4
django-environ==0.8.1
django-heroku==0.3.1
docutils==0.17.1
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
frozendict==2.0.6
genanki==0.11.0
h11==0.13.0
idna==3.2
importlib-metadata==4.8.1
keyring==23.2.1
numpy==1.22.3
openpyxl==3.0.9
outcome==1.1.0
packaging==21.0
pandas==1.4.2
pkginfo==1.7.1
psycopg2-binary==2.8.6
pycparser==2.21
Pygments==2.10.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.0
pystache==0.6.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0
PyYAML==5.4.1
readme-renderer==30.0
requests==2.26.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rfc3986==1.5.0
selenium==4.1.0
six==1.16.0
sniffio==1.2.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.2
tqdm==4.62.3
trio==0.19.0
trio-websocket==0.9.2
twine==3.4.2
tzdata==2022.1
urllib3==1.26.6
webencodings==0.5.1
whitenoise==6.2.0
wsproto==1.0.0
zipp==3.6.0
```

Is there some idea about what is happening?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: @furas, Ok, I will edit it.

Comment: 1) What is `Railway`? 2) OS and version you are running this on? Add answers as update to your question. 3) Why aren't you using the latest version, 2.9.3?

Comment: @N3CR0M4NC3R: Another package within your `requirements.txt` depends on `psycopy2`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, 
1) Railway is an infrastructure platform that is similar to Heroku. 
2) Debian
3) I saw a django app that was working in Railway, and i saw that it was using that version in its dependencies, so i replaced the original version of psycopg-2 "2.9.3" to "2.8.6", but it still has the same error.

I think that the problem is that at the moment of deployment, it still installs psycopg2 instead of psycopg2-binary, I don't know why

Comment: I would take the advice from this, "WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1.2 is available." and upgrade `pip`. Newer versions of `pip` have gotten better about dependency tracking. In case this is the issue @MauriceMeyer raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running [`johnnydep`](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep) on your requirements.txt, shows that `django-heroku` depends on `psycopg2`:

```
>>> johnnydep django-heroku
2022-07-19 17:03:28 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=django-heroku parent=None
2022-07-19 17:03:30 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=dj-database-url>=0.5.0 parent=django-heroku
2022-07-19 17:03:32 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=django parent=django-heroku
2022-07-19 17:03:37 [info     ] init johnnydist                [johnnydep.lib] dist=psycopg2 parent=django-heroku
2022-07-19 17:03:45 [warning  ] Created temporary directory: /private/var/folders/0t/p6l6_9qd15bb9qx6bq2mrt1r0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-q2agslxa
....
```

**Notes:**
1.) I stopped after the first match (possibly there are more dependencies).
2.) I dont know if it is sufficient to put `psycopg2-binary` at the beginning of your requirements.txt, to prevent `psycopg2` needed to get installed.

Comment: This was the answer, I removed django-heroku and it is fixed now, Thanks!.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting "django-heroku" from requirements.txt and also removing it from settings.py file solved my issue