# Deployment problem with railway and django

Tags: django, deployment, railway

When doing the deployment with Raiway I have a perhaps very common error because I found it in this answer [Why do I get this error when I deploy a Django App in Railway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73028024/why-do-i-get-this-error-when-i-deploy-a-django-app-in-railway) but the problem is that none of the possible solutions they mention have worked for me.
What should I do to solve my error?

---

**Structure of my project**

```
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\apps
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\blog
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\files
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\static
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\templates
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\apps\publicaciones
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\apps\publicaciones\migrations
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\apps\publicaciones\__pycache__
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\apps\publicaciones\migrations\__pycache__
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\blog\settings
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\blog\__pycache__
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\blog\settings\__pycache__
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\files\imagenes
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\static\css
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\static\images
C:\Users\Jesus\OneDrive\Documentos\sideprojects\portafolio\blog\static\js
```

---

**requirements.txt**

```
﻿asgiref==3.7.2
contourpy==1.1.1
cycler==0.12.1
distlib==0.3.7
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==4.2.7
django-ckeditor==6.7.0
django-js-asset==2.1.0
filelock==3.13.1
fonttools==4.43.1
gunicorn==21.2.0
kiwisolver==1.4.5
matplotlib==3.8.0
numpy==1.26.0
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.1.1
Pillow==10.0.1
platformdirs==3.11.0
prettytable==3.9.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pyparsing==3.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
setuptools==68.2.2
simpy==4.1.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
static3==0.7.0
tzdata==2023.3
wcwidth==0.2.8
whitenoise==6.6.0
```

---

**Error**

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c python -m venv --copies /opt/venv && . /opt/venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


Error: Docker build failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had this exact problem - Railway is running Django 3.8 so if you’re running a newer version on local machine (I am on 4.2) your packages in requirements.txt might not be right versions to work with older version of Django. I just manually changed numpy version to v1.25.0 from v1.26.0 in requirements.txt after running pip freeze, which fixed the error and I’m up and running now. I’d check them all though if still getting error. If you look further up in build logs above error it should mention the package that’s giving you problems.